# How do I select a color to paint various rooms in my home? What color guides are best?

Tags: painting

I am prepare to paint my "old" house rooms, to clean it up.

But I do not know how to select a color to paint my bedroom, my baby room, and other living room.

This house did not have too much light because is on base floor surround with buildings and I wish for bright colors that make people relax on bedroom.

Are there any general guides to help me out on this ? Or any sites with ideas or proposals.

Comment: This could easily be closed as subjective - as people's colour preferences are just that. It might be worth editing the question to make it clear that you are actually looking for guides etc (as you mention) and *not* specific colour advice.

Comment: I change my question to make it not objective. I really am new on this and I do not even know that there are too many choices on that, that can be objective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with ChrisF's comment that this is subjective. I doubt you'd share my love of bright fuchsia with lime green trim I have in all my rooms.

That being said, [Behr's "Paint Your Place"](http://www.behr.com/dsm-ext/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=6f7ee50350f4a110VgnVCM1000006b0910acRCRD&siteView=html#;channel=INSPIRATION;vgnextoid=6f7ee50350f4a110VgnVCM1000006b0910acRCRD;view=24) is a tool that allows you to pick colors and add them to a picture you've uploaded to get a better idea of what the finished room would look like.

Comment: Sherwin Williams has the same thing.  But Behr paint is probably (marginally) less expensive...  :)

Answer (score 5):

Some paint stores (as opposed to big-box stores) will, for minimal cost, come out and do a plan for you - they'll walk though the house, take a look at your furniture, art work, carpets, etc and present you with a plan.

For someone with no decorating ability at all, it's money well spent.

Answer (score 4):

- Here's a video about '[Why Color
  Matters](http://www.sherwin-williams.com/do_it_yourself/paint_colors/paint_colors_education/why_color/videos/why_color/index.jsp?contentOnly=true&video=true&width=590&height=422)'.
- Here's a video about [the most common mistakes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwPRnElUOTY) that people make when choosing a color. [Hint: Pick a "dull" color for the walls. Bright and vibrant colors should be used only for accents (or not at all).]
- This page includes tips about on
  [choosing interior and exterior
  colors](http://www.sherwin-williams.com/do_it_yourself/paint_colors/paint_colors_education/choosing_colors/).
- Finally, I highly recommend the ['20th Century Colors of America'](http://www.californiapaints.com/2Colors/20thCenturyHues.html) palette by California Paints.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a web based graphic design tool that assists in selecting color schemes. Of course it's RGB, but it can give you ideas on colors that work well together. http://colorschemedesigner.com/

Play around with it and then go to a paint store and try to find closely matching chips. I used color scheme designer when trying to figure out a good color transition between my dining room and adjacent kitchen. The tool got me into the ball park and I was able to refine with paint chips from the store.

Answer (score 2):

If you (like me) have no sense of color, go with the colors that have been “standard” for the last decade, at least here in America: various lighter shades of gray with a tint of other colors for warmth.  While not terribly exciting, these colors will at least make your home look updated.  Use glossy or semi-glossy paint for trim and flat paint for walls, except maybe kitchen and bathrooms.

The colors will probably be on display at the paint store.  You can also see them in magazines and real estate ads.  To see them in action, go to open houses for new track homes/McMansions (if you have those in Athens).

Answer (score 2):

Go to any paint or big box store, and pick up a couple of the brochures/booklets from the paint companies. They have various color schemes that go together included in them (including the actual paint chips) and so really it's just a matter of picking one you like.

Answer (score 1):

better you have to do is get the color wheel sample,then easy to combine them which color you like.

Answer (score 0):

The selection process for me has been:

- Decide what to paint.
- Take a stab at what vague color might be good. "A light blue."
- Visit store, be overwhelmed by choices, grab a million paint swatches.
- Return home, hold up swatches next to objects that the painted surface will be next to. Winnow down the choices based on what looks good/bad next to other colors in the room.
- Return to store, get paint samples of the remaining choices.
- Paint a portion of the surface, preferably where you can view it next to other objects of other colors in the area.
- Wait for it to dry. Choose a favorite.
- Wait longer. Paints often look different as they dry, particularly matte paints, which start life looking far shinier.
- Test the paint under varying light conditions. How does it look in morning sun? Evening soon? Noontime? What about under artificial lights? In the dark?
- Pick a favorite, return to store, purchase large vat of it, and paint all the things.